# No fitted ARIMA model

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, error-message

I wanted to fit an ARIMA model to a daily database for three years but `auto.arima` couldn't find a model and showed the following error:

```
Unable to fit final model using maximum likelihood. AIC value approximated
```

Is it because ARIMA is not good for data with long seasonality?

Comment: I've used the auto.arima function, but this is not the classical way of fitting a model. It's a tool to help you fit the model, but you need to look at the AC/PACs/Residuals. Daily data might be difficult to fit with an ARIMA model, but I don't think the error message you got from auto.arima tells you anything.

Answer (score 1):

Daily data often involves daily indicators , monthly indicators , weekly indicators , holiday effects along with level shifts/local time trends AND ARIMA structure. Oftentimes there are unusual values that need to be treated.

Comment: thank you. does it mean that I can not use auto.arima for daily data?

Comment: I wouldn't advise it as memory (ARIMA) is often insufficient to characterize the time series.

Comment: Dr Hyndman mentioned in this post http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/#comments that we can use fourier series and use ARIMA to handle holidays in annual data. I followed the same approach and Im stil getting the same error for this line: fit <- auto.arima(y, xreg=cbind(z,holiday)),Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There is often(always) lead effects i.e. days before the holiday and lag effects i.e days after the holiday that are important. Good software can automatically FIND this structure ...deficient software does not. Without having a good structire for important events it is difficult(impossible) to detect particular days of the month that be important AND/OR particular weeks of the month that might be important OR Fridays before a Monday Holiday OR Mondays after a FRiday hooliday ETC....

Comment: Do you mean that Auto.Arima has a hard time fitting a model due to lead and lags for holidays? Im not quite sure as looking at my data, holidays did not have a significant impact on the orders booked one day before and one day after them.

Comment: if that is so then we can put holiday effects aside and consider questions like is there a weekly effect or is there a monthly effect ?

Comment: Fourier models are a very particular deterministic effect and often lead to fitted values that don;t describe / explain the actual. Just examine the residuals from a Fourier Model and it may help decide to see whether or not randomness exists in the residuals (.....very important for tests of necessity and sufficiency ). If you want to continue this dialogue please contact me via my email address.

Comment: I already included weekly and annual seasonality. I used TBATS which gave me a good model. The predictions work fine but it does not give close predictions for weekend. I thought this might be a reason of Holidays that I did not include in my model so I decided to go for Fourier series as TBATS does not let using covariate. I thought as I included weekly and annually seasonality, it should have included different seasonality for weekend but it seems the predictions are very low from the actual values. Is it more helpful if I provide my data here?

Comment: I also wonder how we say forecasts are good. definitely we can not have a perfect model. should we look to see how off the forecasts are from the actual values and say ie. if the forecasts are 10% in average far from the actual data, then the model is a good one? is there any criteria for that?

Comment: You can post your data using dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/business/business-free-trial?_tk=sem_goog_b&_kw=dropbox|e&_net=g&_ad=35064061902|1t1&_camp=sem_google_b_dropbox_us-english&gclid=CKW_6uDG5sACFeRj7Aod3HAAjQ.  There is no hard and fast criteria JUST does your model/equation adequately describe the observed data (i.e. are the residuals free of structure ...)